# Error when creating a data frame: only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following variables: `CFNAIdiff`(first differenced), `HOUSTgr`, `INDPROgr`, `UMCSENTgr`, and `UNRATEgr`(which are growth rates). I want to build an AR model and I am trying to construct a data frame in the following way:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(y = INDPROgr[2:T], INDPROgr = INDRPOgr[1:(T-1)],
                        HOUSTgr = HOUSTgr[1:(T-1)], UMCSENTgr = UMCSENTgr[1:(T-1)],
                        UNRATEgr = UNRATEgr[1:(T-1)], CFNAIdiff = CFNAIdiff[1:(T-1)])
```

However, I encounter the following problem:

> Error in INDPROgr[1:(T - 1)] : 
>     only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

What am I specifying wrong?

Comment: What is T.  Are you sure it is not 0 or 1?

Answer (score 2):

The error is stating that you are trying to subset both positive and negative numbers. Lets make a simple example

```
dat <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:10], B = 1:10)
```

We can subset the data.frame in this example using standard methods as you are doing in your own code

```
dat[0:3,]
```

which will return the first 3 rows. Here 0 is treated as empty row, and thus returns an empty row (different from a row with nulls)

```
dat[0,]
```

Now if we by a mistake end up subsetting by lets say a variable T, and this for some reason is 0 or negative you will get an error, if you want to return any specific rows. This is in turn the case to avoid any conflicts such as

```
dat[c(-1,1),]
```

which technically is trying to return the entire data frame minus the first row, but including the first row equivalent to `rbind(dat[-1,], dat[1,])`.

So if we have some function or script that subsets alike your script

```
dataframe<- data.frame( y = INDPROgr[2:T], 
                        INDPROgr = INDRPOgr[1:(T-1)], 
                        HOUSTgr = HOUSTgr[1:(T-1)], 
                        UMCSENTgr = UMCSENTgr[1:(T-1)], 
                        UNRATEgr = UNRATEgr[1:(T-1)], 
                        CFNAIdiff = CFNAIdiff[1:(T-1)])
```

R will return an error in the case that T is either 0 as `T-1 = -1` meaning you are subsetting `1:(-1)`, or alternatively if T itself is negative, for the same reasons.

As such i suggest checking if T becomes negative or zero somewhere in your code.